# PHP File Upload Recognition help!

Tags: php, image, resize, file-type

### SOLVED MY OWN QUESTION! THANKS EVERYONE FOR THE HELP :)

Ok. I'm having trouble with the code below recognizing the upload `FILE TYPE` and running the correct function. I can upload PNG just fine and it will convert and resize like it should, but GIF and JPEG don't and just return a black image. If I remove the png code and try the others individually they work. I can't figure this out at the moment why when I combine them they won't work. It's like together they all use whatever function comes first, instead of going by the `FILE TYPE`

```
if ($width > $max_width){
    $scale = $max_width/$width;
    if ($_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/png"){
    $uploaded = resizeImagePNG($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
    } elseif ($_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/gif"){
    $uploaded = resizeImageGIF($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
    } elseif ($_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/jpeg" || $_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/pjpeg"){
    $uploaded = resizeImageJPG($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
    }
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['image2resize'] = $large_image_location;
    }else{
    $scale = 1;
    if ($_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/png"){
    $uploaded = resizeImagePNG($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
    } elseif ($_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/gif"){
    $uploaded = resizeImageGIF($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
    } elseif ($_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/jpeg" || $_FILE['image']['type'] = "image/pjpeg"){
    $uploaded = resizeImageJPG($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
    }
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['image2resize'] = $large_image_location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basic debugging first: What does `$_FILE['image']['type']` contain?

Comment: It contains the uploaded image type rather it be PNG/GIF/JPG/JPEG. the html is <input type="file" name="image" />. If I comment out lines and try them individually they work, but not when I try them all together dividing them with if statements.

Comment: small typo, `... || $mi**n**e == "image/pjpeg"){` in the `$scale = 1;` branch. Won't solve the problem, though.

Comment: try commenting out the last `header()` call and add `echo`s inside every if branch to see where the code is going. Also `echo $mime;`.

Comment: I'm testing the verification right now. I see a problem there. I hate when these problems come up on big projects.

Comment: Still debugging the problem. Will report back.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!!!!!!!! The verification was screwing things up. Instead of checking if it's not a image, I checked if it was and it started working. NEW verification -> `if ($mime == 'image/gif' || $mime == 'image/jpeg' || $mime == 'image/pjpeg' || $mime == 'image/png' || $_FILES['image']['size'] < 3000000){ working code here } else { error code here } `. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIGURED IT OUT!!!!!!!! The verification was screwing things up. Instead of checking if it's not a image, I checked if it was and it started working. NEW verification -> if ($mime == 'image/gif' || $mime == 'image/jpeg' || $mime == 'image/pjpeg' || $mime == 'image/png' || $_FILES['image']['size'] < 3000000){ working code here } else { error code here } . Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

edit: combined with Pekka's method for the mime, and rewritten for clarity

You have an error in all your if/elseif comparations. You need to put double == instead of single =

You may use this code that should do the same, but in a cleaner and safer way

```
$info = getimagesize(($_FILE['image']['tmp_name']); 
$mime = $info["mime"];

if ($width > $max_width){
    $scale = $max_width/$width;
} else {
    $scale = 1;
}

switch ($mime)
{
    case "image/png":
        $uploaded = resizeImagePNG($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
        break;

    case "image/gif":
        $uploaded = resizeImageGIF($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
        break;

    case "image/jpeg":
        $uploaded = resizeImageJPG($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
        break;

    default:
        // do a better handling of the error
        die('image type not supported');
}

session_start();
$_SESSION['image2resize'] = $large_image_location;
```

Also, don't rely on `$_FILE['image']['type']`, as this value is sent by the browser and an attacker can forge it. Use the `getimagesize()` method for obtaining the filetype as Pekka suggested in his answer.

Comment: I tried `==` and `===` and it won't work. Also, I did try `$imgtypesource = $_FILE['image']['type'];` before and that didn't work. I've very confused by why this isn't working together.

Comment: I've tried that too. I think the problem could lie else where. It's like when I do get all of them to work together, they don't convert the image just change the name to whatever.jpg. I posted the complete code above how I had it. You can comment out the lines where I was having problems and see that the code will convert and resize the images right. As soon as you uncomment the code, it won't work right.

Answer (score 2):

@Carlos answers your question.

As a side note, I wouldn't rely on the MIME type server by the user's browser at all, and use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) to detect the file type instead.

```
$info = getimagesize(($_FILE['image']['tmp_name']); 
$mime = $info["mime"];
```

that is safer.